# Zero termination when casting a char array to string?

Tags: c++

I have this simple piece of code which reverses a string:

```
# include <string>

string str = "abcd";
char *ch = new char[str.length()];

for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < str.length(); i++, j--)
    ch[j] = str[i];

str = string(ch);
cout << str;
```

This works fine, however I was wondering if the char array `*ch` must be zero terminated (perhaps it just works ok. because by chance there happens to be a `0` at memory position `ch + str.length()`. Therefore I've written the following quick test:

```
string str = "abcd";
char *ch = new char[str.length()];

for (int i = 0, j = str.length() - 1; i < str.length(); i++, j--)
    ch[j] = str[i];

// note: illegal memory access, just a quick test
ch[str.length()] = 'a';

str = string(ch);
cout << str;
```

In the above code it is ensured that `*ch` is never zero terminated. To my suprise the code still works ok, I can't get my head around this. How can `str = string(ch)` result in "dbca" when at `ch[str.length]` there is 'a'; I would either expect a memory error or "dbcaa" as a result.

Comment: lenght instead of length

Comment: There's no way that code can "work fine". It may appear to work. Sometimes.

Comment: You have to add one more character for c style string (new char[str.length() + 1];)

Comment: Shouldn't `ch[j] = ch[i]` be `ch[j] = str[i]`?

Comment: This is obviously not the real code. Also, `std::reverse` is infinitely more preferable to this hand-written mess.

Comment: It seems hard to believe that you are posting the actual code that you are testing.

Comment: @David, corrected it is a `string` not `String`. `string` is a string object from the c++ standard library. `length()` returns the length of the string.

Comment: you can't "ensure that the string is not 0-terminated".

Comment: @david you are looking at the real code. `length of the string` is a perfectly fine description. It looks like you are unfamiliar with the c++ default libraries.

Comment: If you feel inclined to work with character arrays for some reason, use a plain `std::vector<char> ch(str.begin(), std.end());`.

Comment: @Gio Does the length of the string include a terminator or not? Is it the amount of memory allocated or the amount used? Is it measured in characters or bytes? A term like "the length of the string" is not a perfectly fine description.

Comment: @David it's c++ and using a standard library header called `string`. That basically answers all your questions.

Comment: @bgoldst yes, corrected

Comment: @Gio - To answer your own question, use the debugger.  I'm sure your debugger has a "memory" window, where you can actually see where your code that is broken manifests itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter what you did before this line:

`str = string(ch);`

The reason is that the line above may allocate memory, and the memory manager may have used the memory directly following your `ch` buffer as allocated space.  So the `a` character you wrote there previously has vanished.  Or something else happened during the construction of `str` that assumed that the space you wrote to previously is available.

If you want to know for sure, *use your debugger*.  The `std::string` constructor and implementation will tell you what exactly occurred (that is, if your program even gets this far since you did introduce undefined behavior before the line of code above).

Answer (score 1):

It's called undefined behaviour. It could be there is a zero after the last address of ch so it could appear to work. But you're overwriting memory allocated from the memory manager which will corrupt it, so you will run into trouble in a bigger application.
The memory manager could reserve a few more bytes in debug builds for debug purpose. Try a release build and see what happens

Answer (score 0):

You're code is totally broken, having undefined behaviour.  Specifically...

```
ch[j] = ch[i];
```

...reads from `ch[i]` which is uninitialised memory - as  bgoldst commented it's probably meant to be `str[i]`, then - even if that didn't invalidate any expectations of program behaviour...

```
str = string(ch);
```

...attempts construction using a `ch`, which points to still uninitialised memory that could have any content at all, and will be scanned along until a NUL happens to be hit, some access violation crashes the program, or whatever other undefined behaviour manifests.  If you fixed the loop to copy from `str`, then you'd probably want this to cope with the lack of NUL termination:

```
str = string(ch, str.length());
```

Perhaps the vaguely worthwhile question is *"isn't it almost impossible that I'd have observed (the claimed) `dbca` output despite the above errors?"*.  To that I'd say:

- `dbca` is not `dcba` - which did you actually see?
- garbage characters in memory might not do anything on your terminal, and it's quite possible that attempting to print from where `ch` was allocated printed nothing visible, or e.g. printed some crap then a clear-back-to-the-start-of-line, delete-previous, backspace etc. character code, then happened to hit the memory allocated by the `std::string` object (seemingly lacking a short-string-optimisation buffer), and therefore displayed its contents too.

So - it's not so statistically amazing to constitute evidence for your program somehow having defined behaviour....

Comment: `ch[j] = ch[i];` changed to `ch[j] = str[i]`

Comment: @Gio: and a downvote...?  What's your comment supposed to tell me exactly anyway - that after 3 people telling you they didn't believe you'd posted the real code and you insisting *"you are looking at the real code"* you realised we weren't and posted the code you'd originally run, or that you fixed that and still see the same output?  Did you consider my explanation above about the need for `string(ch, str.length());`, which is true even if you copy the string content from `str` to `ch[]`?

Comment: a) The following change: ch[j] = ch[i]; changed to ch[j] = str[i] was already made before you've posted your answer (as it was pointed out by bgoldst). b) You are looking at real code, cleary I've stripped away the parts of the code that where not important for the question, nevertheless I've made typos while doing that, yes I'm not perfect. c) You are not answering the question.

Comment: @Gio a) from my machine my answer was posted before your update was visible... I don't know how S.O. propagates updates, but it's poor form to go back on details from your question and blame other people for reacting to them b) that's why you should have created a standalone program that demonstrates the program, preferably somewhere like ideone.com where you can check it compiles/runs and even share it, c) `string(ch, str.length());` does address your (only) question "Zero termination when casting a char array to string?" - NOT necessary if you specify the length at construction.